# Using python polars `read_sql` query giving error `BINARY not supported` but there are no binary type columns in my table

Tags: python-polars

New to polars, trying to execute a simple query against a postgresql database where there are no `binary` type fields but I get an error `RuntimeError: db error: ERROR: BINARY is not supported`. I assume I am doing something wrong or I'm ignorant to how to fix. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: are there any boolean type fields in your database? If they are stored as 1 or 0 perhaps they are being interpreted as binary.

Answer (score 2):

A closer look at the docs, and then a look at the connectorx docs, revealed that I need to set the `protocol` to cursor. This fixed the issue.